# TF / Keras error: InputLayer not a Checkpointable

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu

I am trying out the newly added TPU support on Google Colab with the simple cats vs dogs dataset.

After creating a simple CNN, I tried to export the model to TPU. But it failed with error

```
TypeError: Checkpointable._track_checkpointable() passed type <class 'keras.engine.topology.InputLayer'>, not a Checkpointable.
```

Here's the code that I wrote on Colab.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=(150,150), batch_size=20, class_mode='binary')

tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(model, strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu="grpc://" + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])))
```

My guess is I am doing something wrong in `train_generator`. But I am not sure what it is. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using or import `layers` from `Keras` instead of `TensorFlow` like this:

```
from keras import layers,models
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf
```

You will get error like you mention above :

```
TypeError: Checkpointable._track_checkpointable() passed type <class 'keras.engine.topology.InputLayer'>, not a Checkpointable.
```

So, you can import `layers` directly from `TensorFlow` like my code below:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers,models
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf
```

or you can see my full code here:
https://gist.github.com/ilmimris/8218e397dd35ab693404e95db32dc574